# How do I search and make phone call to a person in my contact list?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, phone-call

I am making an Android application that can take voice commands and call that person. For speech to text conversion I am using Google Cloud API. I found Google people API but it only allows to search and update contacts etc. I want to fetch the details and make phone call from my phone number. Twilio was another thing that I found, but it only calls a given number, doesn't search through contacts. And generates a new number, then calls from that number. Also, this way the user will always need to have an active internet connection which would be a limitation.

Can anyone help me with this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Well, searching a name on your contacts may return more then one contact (if you have multiple contacts named "david" for example)
and also, a single contact may have multiple phones, so you wouldn't know which one to call.

If you ignore those two problems, and just randomly want to pick the first matching contacts, and use the first matching phone, then try this:

```
String searchedName = "David";
String[] projection = { Phone.NUMBER };
String selection = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE %" + searchedName + "%";
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    String number = cur.getString(0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    startActivity(intent); // requires permission "android.permission.CALL_PHONE" in AndroidManifest
} else {
    Log.w("CALL", "contact " + searchedName + " wasn't found");
}
cur.close();
```

Comment: the app crashes. I dont know where the problem is. if i give a number directly to cal, it works so i know the problem isnt in there